# Position ALL text on the right of the links without using a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get each link in the html below to sit on the left of the text(paragraph element). So I am attempting to get the link and text on the same line.

**How can I get ALL the text to sit to the right of the hyperlink?**

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left; display: inline; background-color: blue;"><a href="aboutUs.pdf">About Us</a></div>
    <p style="float: left; display: inline; background-color: yellow;">: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
</div>
<div>
    <div style="float: left; display: inline; background-color: blue;"><a href="aboutUs.pdf">About Us</a></div>
    <p style="float: left; display: inline; background-color: yellow;">: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `float` `display: inline`.

```
<div>
    <a href="aboutUs.pdf">About Us</a>
    <p>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
</div>

​div {height:125px;}
​a{height:100%; display:block; float:left; 
    background: lightblue;}
p{height:100%; background:light gray;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jRJd2/)
​

Answer (score 1):

Why do you do inline styling?

```
div > div{float: left; background-color: blue;}
div > p{background-color: yellow;}

<div>
    <div><a href="aboutUs.pdf">About Us</a></div>
    <p>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
</div>
<div>
    <div><a href="aboutUs.pdf">About Us</a></div>
    <p>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fCaFW/

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/fCaFW/1/

Comment: That makes some of the text underneath the hyperlink, I am trying to get all the text to sit on the right of the link